# Are symbolic links supported in vxworks?

Tags: symlink, vxworks

symlink() is not supported in Vxworks.
Is there any other way to create a symbolic link in Vxworks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most VxWorks filesystems don't even support symlinks, so VxWorks doesn't provide any means of creating them. If you have a filesystem which does support symlinks (and already contains some), then VxWorks can read and follow those links.

Comment: So we have to mount the filsystem to vxworks, which already has symbolic links.Thanks a lot.